# Why is the decimal value not showing?

Tags: jquery, html

So i have my jQuery script ready, but i am struggling with 1 problem , if a value is: $ 10 then everything is fine, but when a value is: `$24,99` then it only will show `24` instead of `24,99`.

How can i fix this? this is my source:

http://jsfiddle.net/0L2n8wdt/34/

```
<table width="652" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th align="left">
                <strong>Product</strong>
            </th>
            <th align="left">
                <strong>Product Price</strong>
            </th>
            <th align="left">
                <strong>How much you want?</strong>
            </th>
            <th align="left">
                <strong>Total Price</strong>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td width="210">Fruit:</td>
            <td width="216">$ 10</td>
            <td width="204">
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td width="204"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Drinks:</td>
            <td>$ 22,95</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cards:</td>
            <td>$ 5</td>
            <td>
                <input  type="text"/>
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>Total price of all:</td>
            <td id="total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

```js
$("input").on("keyup", function () {
    var $input = $(this);
    var howMany = parseInt($input.val());
    var unitAmount = parseInt($input.parent().prev().text().replace("$", ""));
    var total = howMany ? howMany * unitAmount : 0;
    $input.parent().next().text("€ " + total);

    var total = 0;
    $("tbody tr td:last-child").each(function () {
        total += parseInt($(this).text().replace("€", "") || 0);
    });
    $("#total").html("€ " + total);
});
```

Comment: Why javascript uses dot (.) not comma (,) as decimal operator. Must be 24.99 * qty. `var unitAmount = parseInt($input.parent().prev().text().replace("$", "").replace(',', '.'));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to change the decimal separator to dot and `parseInt` to `parseFloat`

```
var unitAmount = parseFloat($input.parent().prev().text().replace("$", "").replace(",","."))
```

And after arithmetic operations you have to convert you number back to a string and replace the dot with `,` :

```
 $input.parent().next().text("€ " + (""+total).replace(".",","));
```

For tatal price:

```
var total = 0;
$("tbody tr td:last-child").each(function() {
    total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace("€","").replace(",",".") || 0);
});
$("#total").html( (""+total).replace(".",","));
```

The full demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/o7LwLgj1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

It is happening because you have used `parseInt`, use `parseFloat`.

Secondly, value `22,95` should be `22.95`.

```
var unitAmount = parseFloat($input.parent().prev().text().replace("$", ""));
total += parseFloat($(this).text().replace("€","") || 0);
```

[**See updated DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/0L2n8wdt/35/)

Comment: Thanks but can i also do that . will appears like , ??

Answer (score 0):

```
$input.parent().next().text(total > 0 ? ("€ "+total).replace(".",",") : "");
```

This should work and you will see , instead of .

Answer (score -1):

Because you are using parseInt, use parseFloat instead