# Value of 22,50 showing as 22

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I hope that someone can help me out with this.
So i have a jquery script that shows a calculated price if you select a option from a form.

So if i give the price in the form : 22 , then it will show 22 thats good, but when i change the value in 22,50 or 22.50 it just show 22.

This is my option form value:

```
<option value="1 Day Paris" data-person="22" >1 Day Paris</option>
```

So if some select 2 persons it will show 2 x 22 = 44

But when i change it to:

```
<option value="1 Day Paris" data-person="22.50" >1 Day Paris</option>
```

I still see 22 instead of 22.50

This is the ouput of the jQuery script :

```
var numPeople = $("#num-people option:selected").val();

peoPriceValue += personP;

}

var numPeo = parseInt($("#num-people option").filter(":selected").val());
if (isNaN(numPeo)) numPeo = 0;

;
```

$("#num-people").html("" + numPeo);

```
$("#t-total-value").html("" + parseInt(total + extraCost3London + extraCost3Parijs));
if (total > 0) {
$("#bluebox").show();
}
```

I hope that someone has a solution for me that the decimals like : 22.50 wil appear instead of 22. Thank you very much

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so that we can see what you are trying to-do. The problem might be with the parseInt.

Comment: parseInt means: parse as an integer.

Comment: This is the same problem you had in the question you posted here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30368615/why-is-the-decimal-value-not-showing. It needs to be parseFloat

Comment: I already found the problem i just replaced all parseInt to parseFloat

Answer (score 2):

Try using parseFloat():

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat

Example of difference between parseInt() and parseFloat():

http://jsfiddle.net/kzx1km1w/

```
var numPeo = parseFloat($("#num-people option").filter(":selected").val());
```

Comment: Thanks I already found the problem i just replaced all parseInt to parseFloat